# Is there an efficient algorithm for finding a square root modulo a prime power?

Tags: computational-number-theory

Cipolla's algorithm [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipolla's_algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipolla%27s_algorithm) is an efficient algorithm for finding a square root modulo a prime number. Is there an efficient algorithm for finding a square root modulo a prime power?

Comment: Your link doesn't seem releveant; Cipolla's algorithm does have its own web page (maybe you meant to link to it?)  You mean square root, I assume?  "Finding a quadratic residue" makes it sound like you want something which is a square modulo $q$.

Comment: no need to pile on...


Comment: I changed "quadratic residue" to "square root".

Comment: Cipolla + Hensel's Lemma  should do it.

Comment: If you are lucky, and your prime power $q$ satisfies $\phi(q)=2$ modulo $4$, then for any quadratic residue $n$ modulo $q$ that is prime to $q$ you can calculate a square root as follows: $\sqrt{n}=n^{(\phi(q)+2)/4$, where $\phi$ is the Euler phi function.


Comment: Apparently Hensel's lemma takes $\approx 2e^2(\log p)^2$ bit-operations for computing square-root modulo $p^e$; there seem to be other faster versions also that take lesser time (I would recommend checking Bach and Shallit's book.

Comment: Once you find a square root of $A$ modulo $p$, Newton-Rapheson iteration applied to the polynomial $x^2 - A$ will double the number of $p$-adic digits of accuracy. (This is for $p\ge 3$. For $p=2$ you probably need to start with a square root modulo 8, and the convergence is slower.) The iteration is $x \to (x/2)+(A/2x)$. In other words, if $a^2 \equiv A \pmod{p^n}$ and you set $b=(a/2)+(A/2a)$, then $b^2\equiv A \pmod{p^{2n}}$. 

Comment: @JoeSilverman is it $b=(\frac a2+\frac{A}{2a})\bmod p^n$ or mod $p^{2n}$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Joe Silverman's comment gives the method. (if the square root of A mod p is 0 you have any easy first step.... let $\gcd(A\  ,p^n)=p^j.$ If $j$ is odd, give up, otherwise let $A=p^{2k}B$ and find the $\mod p \ $  square root of $B$ (if it is a quadratic residue.)

I ascertained this by looking at the modular square root code in Maple (a bit tricky to see the subprocedures..).

According to Wikipedia the [Tonelli-Shanks Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli-Shanks_algorithm) is more efficient that Cipolla's for odd primes not of the form $64Q+1$: Let $m$ be the number of bits in the binary expansion of $p$ and $p-1=Q2^S$ with $Q$ odd. Then it is asserted that Cipolla's method is better exactly when $S(S-1)>8m+20$. Of course for even primes neither method is needed.

The designers of Maple seem to have determined or decided that trying $2,3,4,\cdots$ is best for primes under $80$ or so. I wasn't able to understand (in the limited time I put into it) which of the the modular square root methods Maple uses for the prime case for larger primes.

Comment: Excuse me, let's suppose that $\mathrm{gcd}(A,p^{n})=p^{j}$ and $j$ is odd. Then $A$ is not a square modulo $p^{n}$, right?

Comment: Right. Suppose $B$ is a square root $\mod p^n$ and $B=p^iC \dots$

Comment: Can you please explain, how do I find a root modulo p^k if `A mod p = 0`? You said that in this case `you have any easy first step...` - what does it mean? Does having `A mod p = 0` helps in any sense to find root modulo p^k?

Comment: See the comment above. Square B, see what happens

Answer (score 10):

An explicit formula is given in [Tonelli's 1891 note](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/download/PPN252457072_1891/log50.pdf) referred to in the Wikipedia entry on the [Tonelli-Shanks algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm): Given a prime $p>2$ and a quadratic residue $a \bmod p$, let $x$ be a square root of $a \bmod p$. Then for any power $q = p^k$ and $r:=q/p$, the square root of $a \bmod q$ is $x^r \cdot a^e$ where $e := (q - 2r + 1)/2$. Tonelli's proof is straightforward: Square and apply the Fermat-Euler congruence with exponent $\varphi(q)=q-r$ and the fact that $y \equiv z \bmod p$ implies $y^r \equiv z^r \bmod q$.

Comment: Does this formula work always? For example if `a mod p = 0` (and `a != 0`) does it still work? For example `p = 3, k = 4, q = p^k = 3^4 = 81, a = 7`, then roots of `a` modulo `p = 3` are `1, 2`. While `x^r * a^((q - 2 * r + 1) / 2) mod q = 1^27 * 7^((81 - 2 * 27 + 1) / 2) mod q = 3`, but `3^2 = 9` is not equal to `a = 7`, so `3` is not a square root of `a = 7` modulo `81`.

Answer (score 1):

Dickson's History Of Numbers Vol 1 has formulas that find modular square roots for powers of prime modula.  See p215 for Tonelli's algorithm and p218 for Cipolla's algorithm.  Dickson's work can be found online at

https://ia800209.us.archive.org/12/items/historyoftheoryo01dick/historyoftheoryo01dick.pdf

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked [www.ma.utexas.edu/users/voloch/Preprints/roots.pdf](http://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/voloch/Preprints/roots.pdf), by Prof. Voloch and P Barreto?
If I am not mistaken, in certain cases, their work improves on Cipolla's.

Comment: The algorithm on that paper is not an algorithm for taking roots modulo prime powers, it's an algorithm for taking roots on finite fields whose order is a large power of a prime (which are different beasts). 