# Method to solve modular quadratic polynomial

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, algorithms, computational-number-theory, p-adic-numbers

If $q$ is a prime what is the best method to compute roots of a quadratic polynomial $f(x)\equiv0\bmod q^2$ which is of form $x^2+bx+c\equiv0\bmod q^2$ where $b^2-4c\equiv0\bmod q$ and $gcd(b,q)=1$ and the cases are

1. $b^2-4c\equiv0\bmod q^2$ (**most interested**) and
2. $b^2-4c\not\equiv0\bmod q^2$?

If $q$ is composite with prime factorization known what is the best way?

If factorization of $q$ is unknown I believe the problem is at least as hard as factoring.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54936/ is a duplicate

Comment: ... which links to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52081/

Comment: After edit: The case when $p$ divides the discriminant isn't harder. To find the square root in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ the valuation has to be even and then use Hensel's lemma on the unit part. Which by the way is the usual algorithm $x \to 1/2(x+a/x)$ to find square roots.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is the field of $p$-adic numbers. I don't think your question is asked at the right forum.

Comment: So can you explain the answer explicitly for computational number theory purposes? I believe the problem is not exact duplicate. So perhaps reopenable? So is root mod $q^2$ computable in polynomial time? Is there a reference to what you are talking about? $b$ and $q$ may be assumed coprime.

Comment: $p^2|discriminant$ not just $p$ as you mention.

Comment: Yes, I am answering the additional question with $q^2\mid \Delta$. It is an easy extension of the methods described in the linked answer and does not vouch for reopening the question. I won't have time to explain $p$-adic numbers, so please read up on them and how to find square roots there; it is fun.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich Oh I see. Is it just substituting symbol for root as $-b+kq$ in the quadratic and solving for $k\bmod q$?

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich Can you tell me the name for the technique? So I can look it up?

Answer (score 0):

If $q$ is prime then first solve $f(x) \equiv 0 \pmod q$ using the standard expression $\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$; there are three cases for $\sqrt{y} \pmod q$:

1. If $y$ is not a quadratic residue $\operatorname{mod} q$, there are no solutions;
2. If $q \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ then $\sqrt{y} \equiv y^{(q+1)/2} \pmod q$;
3. Otherwise use Tonelli-Shanks.

Then lift the solution(s) from $\operatorname{mod} q$ to $\operatorname{mod} q^2$ using Hensel's lemma.

---

If $q$ is composite with known factorisation, I don't expect there to be a better solution than solving the equation for each prime factor and using the Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: Can you explain the Hensel lifting process for the two solutions?

Comment: @Turbo, it is described in great detail in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma

Comment: $f(x)$ for me is quadratic and the discriminant mod $q$ is $0$ while discriminant mod $q^2$ is not $0$. Are there any complications to applying the technique? Is there anything that would be different?

Comment: In my case $q|f'(root)$ and so there is no inverse of $f'(root)$ where $f(root)\equiv 0\bmod q$ holds and $disc\equiv0\bmod q$. Posted in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4405084/on-hensel-lifting-of-a-particular-quadratic-mod-q2-where-q-is-a-prime.

Comment: Is it possible to avoid Hensel lifting? My equation is of form $$x^2-(a+b)x + ab = 0 \bmod q^2$$ where $a+b=0\bmod q$ and so I get $(x-r)^2=0\bmod q$. I know the answer is not $a,b$ for my purpose but one of the Hensel lifts. So there is no canonical uniqueness conditions for root modulo $q^2$?